# Calculating distance, but stuck with typeerror

Tags: python, pandas

Good day, everyone! Hope you are doing well. I have a code which calculates distance between airport direction using their geographical coordinates. Code works fine when I manually type coordinates. However, when U take input from a file using pandas it has some error. I 've searched thought different websites on how to fix it. People were typing to change to .astype(float), but it didn't help. I 've changed also points to commas, but it didn't help as well. I 've stuck with it, please give me some direction, advice? Thank you. 
the code as following:

```
from math import radians, degrees, sin, cos, asin, acos, sqrt
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('coordinates.xlsx',  names=['from', 'long1','lat1','to','long2','lat2'], index =  False)


def great_circle(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    return 6371 * (
        acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1 - lon2))
    )
great_circle(df['long1'], df['lat1'],df['long2'], df['lat2'])
```

Error: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`

Input from file like this:

```
    from    long1   lat1        to  long2            lat2
0   AKX  57.206667  50.245833   FRU 74.477556   43.061306
1   AKX  57.206667  50.245833   GUW 51.821389   47.121944
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables lat1, lat2 lon1 lon2 are of `Series` type. If you apply sin on them it would not work, thet `sin` function works only with numeric inputs. Check the [Python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html).

Generally speaking, when using vectors (`Series` in `pandas`) or matrix (`pandas` `DataFrame`, numpy) the operators may different, simply because the inputs are different than for usual operators (`Float`, `Int`, `String` versus Vector).

Just modify your code like this :

```
sin(lat1)
```

by

```
lat1.apply(lambda x: sin(x))
```

And the entire code will look like this:

```py
def parse_row(row):
    result = 6371 * acos(row['sin_lat1'] * row['sin_lat2'] + row['cos_lat1'] * row['cos_lat2'] + row['cos_diff'])
    return result


sin_lat1 = df['lat1'].apply(lambda x: sin(x)).reset_index()
sin_lat2 = df['lat2'].apply(lambda x: sin(x)).reset_index()
cos_lat1 = df['lat1'].apply(lambda x: cos(x)).reset_index()
cos_lat2 = df['lat2'].apply(lambda x: cos(x)).reset_index()

lon_diff = df['long1'] - df['long2']
cos_diff = lon_diff.apply(lambda x: cos(x)).reset_index()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sin_lat1', 'sin_lat2', 'cos_lat1', 'cos_lat2', 'cos_diff'])
df['sin_lat1'] = sin_lat1
df['sin_lat2'] = sin_lat2
df['cos_lat1'] = cos_lat1
df['cos_lat2'] = cos_lat2
df['cos_diff'] = cos_diff

new_df = df.applymap(parse_row,axis=1)
```

With this, and applying on your data:

```
from    long1   lat1        to  long2            lat2
0   AKX  57.206667  50.245833   FRU 74.477556   43.061306
1   AKX  57.206667  50.245833   GUW 51.821389   47.121944
```

I got the result :

```
0   0.0
1   3.0
```

You may use also the trigonometric operators in numpy :

[sin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html)

Comment: return 6371 * (
        acos(lat1.apply(lambda x: sin(x)) * lat2.apply(lambda x: sin(x)) + lat1.apply(lambda x: cos(x))  * lat2.apply(lambda x: cos(x)) * cos(lon1 - lon2)).apply(lambda x,y: cos(x-y))
    ) - I have changed to this, but error is same,

Comment: return 6371 * (
        acos(np.sin(lat1) * np.sin(lat2) + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.cos(lon1 - lon2))
    ) - I have changed to this, however, error is same.

Comment: Yes, because I am not sure that * will do the job. You should multiply elementwise. I shall update the answer, wait a bit.

Comment: Thank you, but here is    TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable highlighting the cos_diff = lon_diff(lambda x: cos(x)) :(

Comment: Catalina,mulțumesc! I used np it solved everything,  dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2) **2
    c = 2 * np.arctan2(a**0.5, (1-a)**0.5)
    d = R * c

Comment: Cu placere! But let us speak English so that anyone understand :-). I updated the answer (after testing). Yes that is another way to do that. Check also the pandas official documentation, it is very useful, if you want to understand how this works.

Comment: `'Series' object is not callable` error occured because I ommited to add `apply` before. I had `lon_diff(lambda x: cos(x))` instead of `lon_diff.apply(lambda x: cos(x))`. The error means that a Series cannot be used as a function. It was a slip of mine. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what level of accuracy you are looking for - but, vincenty method gives better accuracy (accurate to within 1 mm or better!) haversine one.

If you are trying to just plug it into your code, this [package](https://pypi.org/project/vincenty/) might worth a try!

```
from vincenty import vincenty
boston = (42.3541165, -71.0693514)
newyork = (40.7791472, -73.9680804)
vincenty(boston, newyork)
>>> 298.396057
```

You can even look at the `vincenty` from `geopy` module for that matter!

(Sorry, this is not a direct answer to your question, but, you already seem to have got the answer for your existing issue!)

Comment: That library seems interesting, it looks worth to ne tested. What is that value ytou obtain? If it is a distance, which measure unit? Is it a cosine similarity between two vectors?

Comment: It's in km. If you want miles you can pass `miles = True` like here : `vincenty(boston, newyork, miles=True)`

Comment: Also, I would say may be check out the performance of your code v/s this package - like which is faster. Also, if your calculation is likely to be in the > 10 km range, you probably won't care about the 1mm accuracy there!

Comment: Good idea to check the processing time for both. It is the author who should make those tests, as being the only person to have acess to the entire data.

Comment: Yeah! I guess the author should have added comparison - I'll check out if this has github with that! But, even if it's not there one can just take 100 of one's own data points - and have quick check.